# Consulta a la API graphQL de Wiki.js con javascript vainilla (CORS error)

Tags: javascript, html, api, graphql, vscode-live-server

Estoy desarrollando una SPA desde la que haría consultas a una app en wiki.js. Desde el playground de la wiki (url/graphql) no tengo ningún problema (también hice la prueba desde postman y anda bien) pero cuando hago la consulta desde mi localhost me da este error:

> [Error] No se pudo establecer conexión con el servidor.
> [Error] Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:4000/graphql due to access control checks.
> [Error] Failed to load resource: No se pudo establecer conexión con el servidor. (graphql, line 0)
> [Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: Load failed
> promiseEmptyOnRejected
> promiseReactionJob

Este es el código con el que hago el llamado:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',       
             'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
},
  body: JSON.stringify({ query: `
  query{
    pages {
      list{
        title
        id
        path
      }
        single(id:13){
        title
        id
        path
        content
      }
    }
  }
  ` }),
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => console.log(res))
```

Parece ser un problema de CORS, pero no estaría pudiendo solucionarlo.

Comment: Ahí edité la query tal cual la hago en playground

Comment: No... solo un index.html con el script del index.js que tiene solo el código que puse ahí (no conozco webpack ni se bien cómo sería lo del proxy)

Comment: Esta web que desarrollaste, la creaste con node/express? o por ejemplo con el [tutorial de graphql](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/running-an-express-graphql-server/)?

Comment: No, pero entiendo que eso es para desarrollar una api GraphQL propia, no para hacer consultas..

Comment: Parece un problema de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) por eso quiero saber desde donde o como estas corriendo tu localhost, porque puede que configurando un proxy, lo puedas resolver.

Comment: En mi localhost hay lo que te conté y no más: un index.html que no tiene más que la estructura base y el script con el src del índex.js (y en ese índex no hay otra cosa que lo que estoy mostrando acá)

Comment: otro detalle que te comparto,`fetch` esta tratando de comunicarse con el endpoint `http://localhost:4000/graphql` , eso me hace pensar que de tu lado tienes un server `GraphQL` corriendo en ese localhost:4000, ¿no sería que ahi debes poner el endpoint de `wiki.js` para `graphql` (la url del playground de la wiki (url/graphql))?

Comment: Tenés razón, yo puse esa url para no poner la personal y eso se presta a confusión, pero la url con la que estoy haciendo las pruebas es otra (y está en un servidor remoto)

Comment: No hay nada mal en el código. De hecho copié y pegué el código que usa Postman y da el mismo error

Comment: Es un problema de CORS, sí, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo

Comment: Bien, yo comenzaría con [esta lectura](https://pretagteam.com/question/add-multiple-proxy-in-package-json) y despues intentaría crear un proxy para el path `graphql`, y este path sería mi `url` en `fetch`.

Comment: Para eso tendría que hacer el backend en express

Comment: Esto no me queda claro "En mi localhost hay lo que te conté y no más". ¿Como se levanta ese localhost? ¿Algún contenedor...?

Comment: con la extension live-server de visual studio code

Comment: Como parece un problema de CORS claro, intenta añadir a tu variable URL la siguiente cadena, para añadir a la petición la cabecera CORS:

`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

Comment: Hola Sergio, buscando una solución encontré eso pero tampoco funciona: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

Comparto la configuración con la cual, logré establecer una conexión exitosa entre `vscode live-server` y la [`API graphQL` de `Github`](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/forming-calls-with-graphql#example-query):

```
const url = "https://api.github.com/graphql";
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json',       
    'Authorization': 'Bearer token'//aqui va tu token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query: `
      query { 
        repository(owner: "user", name: "repoName") { 
          description
        }
      }`
    }),
  }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => console.log(res))
```

No hubo necesidad de configurar el proxy de `live-server`, lo cual me sorprendio pues yo tenía conocimiento de los problemas CORS/proxy.

Puede que esta configuración les sirva de ejemplo base, para consumir otros endpoints **graphQL** que requieran credenciales.

#### Proxy live-server

Se puede intentar configurar el proxy para live-server, hay que editar el archivo settings.json:

> Users>tu_usuario>Library>Application Support>Code>User>settings.json

Se debe agregar esta propiedad:

```
"liveServer.settings.proxy":{
        "enable": false,//aqui va true
        "baseUri": "/",
        "proxyUri": "http://127.0.0.1:80"//puede que aqui vaya tu endpoint graphql http://localhost:4000
    }
```

Luego la variable `url`que consume `fetch`, quedaría como:

```
let url = "/graphql"
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Es exactamente igual a mi código...

Comment: ¿Que me dices de la url? ¿Tambien estas pasando el endpoint de wiki.js para graphql? De mi lado funciona este ejemplo para GitHub, esta muy interesante la situación, saludos

Comment: Sí, tengo bien puesta la url. Acabo de probar haciendo la consulta a la api de GitHub y si puedo. No sé qué onda...

Comment: He puesto la info de como configurar proxy para `live-server`, es lo que yo trataría de hacer, suerte colega

Comment: No me dio resultado, pero bueno, gracias por el esfuerzo